# How to Find Specific Words in Last 10 Lines of File with Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have searched the vast Internet and cannot find a way to look for specific words in, and only in, the last 10 lines of a text file using batch code. So far, I have this which looks for text in the whole file.

```
>nul find "Example Words" examplefile.txt && (
REM Found...
goto next) || (
REM Not Found...
goto home
)
```

So, again, what this does is it searches the **whole** file for *Example Words*, while what I need is a way to look for those words in only the **last 10 lines**?

Comment: Is it the last **10** or the last **2** lines? please clarify!

Comment: @aschipfl: Exists `10` types of people: those that do know binary system and those that don't...

Comment: Hehe, @Aacini... I hope the OP clarifies though...

Comment: @aschipfl: Well, if the `10` is written in binary, it means _two_ lines! Note that the OP did not wrote **last 2 lines**, but **last two lines**. **`;)`**

Comment: I did clarify in the question. 10 lines

Comment: Yes, I got that, @Aacini, although I did not recognise "two" vs. "2"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, count the number of lines present in the text file:

```
for /F %%C in ('^< "examplefile.txt" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
```

Then determine how many lines to be skipped (all but the last 10 lines, for instance):

```
if %COUNT% GTR 10 (set /A "SKIP=COUNT-10") else (set "SKIP=0")
```

Finally, use the [`more` command](http://ss64.com/nt/more.html) to actually skip the lines:

```
more +%SKIP% "examplefile.txt" | > nul findstr /L /I "Example Words" && (
    rem Found
    goto next
) || (
    rem Not Found
    goto home
)
```

Use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) rather than `find` to specify multiple <kbd>SPACE</kbd>-separated search strings or words (like `Example` and `Words` here). Use the `/I` option to do case-insensitive searches.

Note that `more` expects user input when the input files contains 65535 or more lines. It converts <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> to <kbd>TABs</kbd>, but this should not change anything here as you are not interested in them anyway for the search since you are searching for words only.

---

Here is a more complicated and less efficient approach relying on a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), using also the `COUNT` variable as derived above. It needs the `skip` option of `for /F`, which is build as follows:

```
set /A "SKIP=COUNT-10"
if %SKIP% GTR 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%SKIP%") else (set "SKIP=")
```

Then there is the aforementioned `for /F` loop:

```
for /F "%SKIP% delims=" %%L in ("examplefile.txt") do (
    echo(%%L| > nul findstr /L /I "Example Words" && (
        rem Found
        goto next
    )
)
ren Not Found
goto home
```

Every line is searched individually in the loop; as soon as a match is encountered, `goto next` is executed; `goto` breaks the loop context, hence `for /F` does no longer execute any commands inside of its body.

Regard that `for /F` ignores empty lines, and also such beginning with a semicolon (`;`) per default. Some special characters (`^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`) may cause trouble with the `echo` command in the pipe (`|`).

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work. Whenever I add this to my code, it instantly closes.

Comment: What did you add to your code, and what is exactly the problem?

Comment: In this I replaced the section after :AfterQPos with... `for /F %%C in ('^< "%Appdata%\.minecraft\logs\latest.log" find /C') do set "COUNT=%%C"` New Line `if %COUNT% GTR 10 (set /A "SKIP=COUNT-10") else (set "SKIP=")` New Line `more +%SKIP% "%appdata%\.minecraft\logs\latest.log" | > nul findstr /L /I "Connecting to the server..." && (
    rem Found
    goto next
) || (
    rem Not Found
    goto home
)` When I do this, instead of repeating until it finds the words, it instantly closes.

Comment: Also, I put a `pause` after the first `for /F %%C...` and it says `FIND: Parameter format not correct` then after that I press enter to unpause and when it runs `if %COUNT% GTR 10 (set /A "SKIP=COUNT-10") else (set "SKIP=")` it instantly closes the program, even when it's not done and has no where to go.

Comment: I don't know what `:AfterQPos` is; neither do I know `:next` and `:home` labels you mentioned in your question. My code simply searches the words in the last 10 lines in the text file, it does not wait until the words are present there; you would have to establish a loop for this. Anyway, do not run the batch file by double-click; open a command prompt window, manoeuvre to the directory containing the batch file (by `cd`) and enter the name of the batch file to run it; so you are able to read any appearing error messages. Also consider to remove `@echo off` temporarily for debugging...

Comment: `find /C` should actually read `find /C /V ""` -- I just corrected that in my answer; sorry!

Comment: It works now, thankyou! If I have anymore issues, I will move this discussion to chat.

Comment: I cannot move the discussion to chat because I have not enough reputation. However, my code [here](http://pastebin.com/rcPgvrCH), when run, does as it should up until, it would seem, the section of code that you gave me. The words "Connecting to the server..." are not present in the file at all and certainly not in the last 10 lines but yet it still goes to :end. Why?

Comment: If you want to find `Connecting to the server...` literally, change the `findstr` command line: `findstr /C:"Connecting to the server..."`

Answer (score 0):

This includes/excludes n lines from top or bottom of a file.

**Cut**

```
filter cut {t|b} {i|x} NumOfLines
```

Cuts the number of lines from the top or bottom of file.

```
t - top of the file
b - bottom of the file
i - include n lines
x - exclude n lines
```

**Example**

```
cscript //nologo c:\folder\filter.vbs cut t i 5 < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

The script filter.vbs

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 

    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    LineCount = 0
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        LineCount = LineCount + 1
        .AddNew
        .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
        .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
        .UpDate
    Loop

    .Sort = "LineNumber ASC"

    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
            .filter = "LineNumber < " & LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
            .filter = "LineNumber > " & LCase(Arg(3))
        End If
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" then
        If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
            .filter = "LineNumber > " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3))
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
            .filter = "LineNumber < " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
        End If
    End If

    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Here's a example code counting folders by counting the lines in the `dir` command output.

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@CD C:\newfolder
@set count=0
@For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\newfolder\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
@rem     If !Count! gtr 1 echo Num of folders
)

Set /a num=%random% %% %Count% + 1 
Echo %num%

@For /f "skip=%num% delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\newfolder\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
Echo this is nth random folder
Echo Copy "%~dpnx0" "%%A"
Exit /b
)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is there no way to do this in batch?

Comment: Cause there is. It will be painfully slow.

Comment: Use a `for /f` loop, count the lines in delayed expansion mode, read the file a second time with `for /f` discarding all but the last n lines worked out in step 1.